# How to create a Global Variable in Wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am new to the [WSO2 esb](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/),Am working with wso2esb 4.7.0,wso2dss 3.0.0.

I want to create a global variable and call that variable into my proxy services

My proxy is as shown below

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Get_details" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
 <target endpoint="Endpoint">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>        
     <property name="username" expression="//username/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <property name="password" expression="//password/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <log>
        <property name="username" expression="get-property('username')"/>
        <property name="password" expression="get-property('password')"/>
     </log>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <p:select_login_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
              <p:username>$1</p:username>
              <p:password>$2</p:password>
           </p:select_login_op>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('username')"/>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('password')"/>
        </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="Get"       expression="fn:concat('http://192.168.1.201:9764/services/', 'Get_details')"/>
            <header name="To" expression="get-property('Get')"/>
        <send>
        <endpoint>
           <default/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
      </inSequence>
       <outSequence>
     <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
   </proxy>
```

In the above proxy i have used concat function to combine my Url and Service name,here what i want to do is i want to use a variable instead of url by creating a global variable and assign the url as its value  and use that variable in the concat function instead of url in this proxy and several other proxy also.

How can  this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the value as a [Local Registry Entry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Local+Registry+Entries) and use it from inside proxy services. For example if I have a Local Entry called 'MyURL' I can use it as below

```
synapse:get-property('MyURL')
```

Another example;

```
 <log level="custom">
    <property name="MyURL" expression="synapse:get-property('MyURL')"/>
 </log>
```

Answer (score 2):

A sample for **ESB 5.0.0**:

Suppose we have the current time in a property named `nowTimeProp`.

```
<property name="nowTimeProp" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default"/>
```

**Storing** the property in the registry:

```
<property name="conf:/resource/yourResourceName" type="STRING" expression="$ctx:nowTimeProp" scope="registry"/>
```

Later, we'd like to **read** the property from the registry:

```
<property name="lastStoredInstantProp" expression="get-property('registry', 'conf:/resource/yourResourceName')"/>
```

Comment: could you please tell how to delete it? <property name="var1" action="remove" scope="registry" /> doesn't work for me